# Why is paintComponent executed 2 times?

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

I have following code:

```
        canvas=new MembershipFunctionComponent(functions);
        canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension((int)this.getWidth(), (int)this.getHeight()));
        canvas.addMouseListener(canvas);
        pane.add(canvas);
```

MembsershipFunctionComponent extends JComponent. Why is paintComponent method executed 2 times?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`paintComponent` can get called at pretty much any time by the Swing framework. Examples of when this might happen:

- Any time a component is resized
- Any time part of the component is revealed (for example in a scrollable window)
- Any time the repaint() method is called on your component (or possibly a parent or sub-component)
- Any time there is a layout change

None of this should worry you - you should just write your code so that it doesn't care how many times paintComponent is called.

Comment: exactly which is one reason program logic should not reside in this method. 1+